# iOS 8 Safari in Iphone, appending to autocompleted url

Tags: safari, ios, url, auto-complete

In iOS 8 Safari, when it autocompletes a url one begins to type, it would be useful if we could move the cursor to the end of the autocompleted url so we can append more path and file info.

Is it possible to append an autocompleted URL in Safari for iPhone ?

Comment: I would like to know that as well, right now the only way i know is to actually let it go to the correct website then in the web address window (not search) add to the web address usually something like /bla/bla to get to the sub directories of that web site. Or use backspace to remove unwanted and type correct stuff. Yes complicated :(

Answer (score 1):

Backspace will return you to the point you were last typing.

Tap/hold will turn the autocomplete into 'real' text you can then edit - but you can't fill from halfway down the potential URL, it becomes a new full text string that you need to work with, as though you'd already typed it all.

So, for instance, typing `app` will turn into `apple.com` Tap/hold will 'freeze' that allowing you to then complete `apple.com` by typing `/knowledgebase` but if you wanted `apple.net` you would first have to delete the `com` before continuing.

Comment: When I tap and hold and then type, the whole uri is replaced by my new text :(

Comment: first tap/hold can make a 'selection' with the blue lines & handles at the beginning & end. Tap again will clear that. Once you turn it to 'text' it then behaves like any other text string.

Comment: Tapping again makes the cursor stay at the middle of the string not at the end of it.

Comment: then you simply have to work on it like any other string, same as if you notice a typo way back in the middle of a text message.